# Ionic 2 - Input ‘Go’ field on Keyboard is doing two things

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an Ionic App for iOS & Android and so far I have a form where users can upload or take a photo and then fill in some other information and submit the form.

My issue:

Currently when the user goes to an Input to enter some extra text there is a go button at the bottom of the keyboard. If the user clicks this 'Go' button it tries to submit the form along with opening the `choosePicture()` function I have.

What happen when I click the
[Go button - it opens the Library](https://gyazo.com/0bffed56b5c4743b061b54aa868af82d)

The HTML

```
<ion-item class="file-upload">
    <button  class="btn btn-block" ion-button (click)="choosePhoto()">Choose a Photo</button>
    <span class="sep"></span>
    <button class="btn btn-block" ion-button (click)="takePicture()">Take a Picture</button>
    <div class="uploaded-img">
        <input type="file" value="" formControlName="hazardImage" hidden />
        <span class="img-desc">Please Take or Upload an Image.</span>
        <div class="img-picked" *ngIf="base64Img">
            <img [src]="base64Img" alt="Hazard Picture" />
            <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Test Image" /> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-item>

<small class="small-title">Where is the Hazard Location? (required)</small>
<ion-item class="input-box">
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="hazardLocation" [class.invalid]="!hazardForm.controls.hazardLocation.valid && (hazardForm.controls.hazardLocation.dirty || submitAttempt)"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

The TypeScript:

```
choosePhoto()
{
    this.Camera.getPicture({
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: this.Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        sourceType: this.Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit: true
    }).then((ImageData) => {
        // console.log(ImageData);
        this.base64Img = ImageData;
        this.hazardForm.patchValue({
            hazardImage: this.base64Img
        });
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

I don't understand why the `Go` Button is opening the function for choosing a photo :/

Comment: What was the `Go` button supposed to do instead?

Comment: Probably replacing <button> element with <a> or any other can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the behaviour of the 'Go' keyboard button with:

```
@ViewChild('input-box') inputElm: ElementRef;
@HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
keyEvent(e) {

if(!e.srcElement) return; //browser fix
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
if (code === 13) {
  if (e.srcElement.tagName === "INPUT") {
    e.preventDefault();
    //handle other behaviours
  }
}
};
```

Comment: Tottaly forgot about `preventDefault()`, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `<input>` for "Hazard Location" as a Form since there is a  `formControlName="hazardLocation"` attribute. This makes the `Go` or form submit button appear in the mobile keyboard.

Instead, you should have it as a normal input field like this

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hazardLocation">
```

Comment: Hmmm... I don't mind it having `formControlName` as I need to capture the data and send to my server - my problem is the Go button on the keyboard is opening my photo library - like I have shown in the link I attached :/ I want the 'Go' button to be changed to a 'Done' button if I can but if not I'd rather it not open the Photo Library

Comment: Please try the change I showed you. It still binds the input with `hazardLocation` and updates it automatically for you to capture and send to server. This is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I tried what you showed and still not good the 'Go' button is opening the Choose Photo which opens up the Users Library